# underscore.js no data outside _.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm retrieving a JSONp file with jQuery's $.ajax. I can't figure out how to make the underscore loop work...

in success I've this this code:

```
                success : function(response) {

                        var dataResp = '';
                        _.each(response.results, function(response, index) {

                                    var dataResp = response;

                                    var prodName = dataResp.trackName;
                                    var prodUri = dataResp.trackViewUrl;
                                    var prodUri = dataResp.trackViewUrl;
                                    var prodUri = dataResp.trackViewUrl;
                                    var prodPrice = Math.round(dataResp.trackPrice);
                                    var prodImg = dataResp.artworkUrl100.replace("100x100bb.", "700x700bb.");

                                    console.log(prodName); // returns all product names, and that's fine

                        }, this);

                        console.log(dataResp); // dataResp is empty


                                var html = "";
                                var compiled = _.template($("#product-structure").html(), dataResp );

                                _.each(dataResp, function(data) { // loop to compile template for all the elements inside the jsonp response
                                  html += compiled(data);
                                });

                                $('#data').html(html); // append to html the compiled template


                }
```

I use underscore.js for the templating part but I can't figure out why my data isn't available outside that _.each loop...

here my template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="product-structure">
<%= data.img %>
<%= data.title %>
<%= data.price %>
<%= data.uri %>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the _.map function which returns a new array. I am assuming you want an object returned with those values.

This code will return an array of objects, each object will contain the prodName, prodUri, prodPrice, and prodImg.

```
var dataResp = _.map(response.results, function(response, index) {
    return {
        prodName: response.trackName,
        prodUri: response.trackViewUrl,
        prodPrice: Math.round( response.trackPrice ),
        prodImg: response.artworkUrl100.replace( "100x100bb.", "700x700bb")
    };
}, this);
```

Comment: thank you. Didn't know about the mapping. Mapping works, but when I try to loop and then append #data it appends 1 object and it's empty...

Comment: whoa! never mind I've found out what was the error. Thank you again fayzaan!!

Answer (score 0):

You have use the `var` keyword twice. Inside the loop you have:

`var dataResp = response;` which creates a new variable called dataResp. Since variables have function scope in js, this variable *only exists in the function in which it is created*. The solution is to switch it to `dataResp = response;` without the `var`